# When I input a word, the program is not understanding the word even though the if function puts up the exact same word that was inputted

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double word;

    cout<<"write your word"<<endl;
    cin >> word;
    if (word == 'hello')
        cout << "hello world" << endl;
}
```

When I input 'hello', it doesn't return "hello world" and just dies out. What must I do so that it will understand the word that I'm inputting?

Comment: There are no "hello world" in your code, so it won't return that. Also note that `int` will not accept strings.

Comment: Please explain what the code is supposed to do and include error messages in the question

Comment: You should check the success of `cin >> word;` e.g. `if (!(cin >> word)) std::cerr << "Wrong input!\n";`. Doing this you will recognize that you cannot input text into a `double`. Furthermore, `'hello'` is a constant character (and not even a valid). For a constant string you had to use double quotes (e.g. `"hello"`). (Other languages like e.g. Python are more generous about this but C++ is really strict about the quote meaning.)

Comment: @Scheff `'hello'` is a multi-character character literal and its value is implementation-defined. In some environments this is invalid because they try to interpret as large (5 bytes) integer that won't fit `int` (4 bytes) in their environments.

Comment: @MikeCAT I hardly can imagine that there is any (common) platform where `'hello'` forms a valid character. However, even if it was - that surely was not the intention of OP (as you mentioned in your answer as well). ;-)

Comment: @MikeCAT _Although not specified by the C or C++ standard, most compilers (**MSVC is a notable exception**) implement multicharacter literals as specified in B: the values of each char in the literal initialize successive bytes of the resulting integer_ (from [Character literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal)) Maybe, that's reason that I'm struggling to imagine senseful multibyte character usage - VS is my tool for daily business. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie in C++ thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double` is for storing floating-point numbers. You should use `std::string` to store strings.

Also `''` is for representing characters. You should use `""` to represent strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> // add this

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word; // change type

    cout<<"write your word"<<endl;
    cin >> word;
    if (word == "hello") // use "", not ''
        cout << "hello world" << endl;
}
```